# Issue on "theme get" command shopify

Tags: shopify, liquid, shopify-template

I have a theme on my store which I want to set up on local machine. I'm using the command

**theme get --password=[your-api-password] --store=[your-store.myshopify.com] --themeid=[your-theme-id]**

with my valid credentails.
But I'm getting an error in the terminal as follows :

**invalid environment [development]: (Could not get absolute root bath: getwd: no such file or directory)**

Why am I getting this error? I was using this command till yesterday to fetch the theme but suddenly today I'm getting this error. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure it is not the following:

- theme configure --password=[your-api-password] --store=[your-store.myshopify.com] --themeid=[your-theme-id]
- theme download

At that point you have the files, which you can place into git with **git init && git add . && git commit -m 'initial commit'**

Then you load the code in your editor, and follow up with a **theme watch**